# Localhost doesnot work

Tags: windows, wamp

I installed wamp server on xp. During the installation it did not show any error/warning message.
Then i start it & type `http://localhost/` in url bar but it just show a blank page.
I also checked

```
notepad C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

their is no restriction for localhost.

Help.
Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

- Have you made sure that your `index.html` page isn't blank? If you get a literally blank page, it means that the server is taking connections, and might just be serving you an empty file.
- If you are using PHP for your `index.php` file, make sure that the module is enabled in `httpd.conf` (if it's split over several files, look for one mentioning modules.)
- If there are any installation `.bat` files in the installation directory, try running them again.

If you get an **error page** when you connect, not a blank page, make sure that your firewall isn't blocking the server.

Comment: Thanks friend,

actually that was happened because Fire wall was ON.

Thanks again..

Comment: OK. Glad to see you got it working!